# gridview PagerTemplate causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-select

The code below is causing an error when uploaded to IIS (runs just fine on local dev machine)

```
<PagerTemplate>
             <asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%">
                 <asp:TableRow>
                     <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left">
                         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                     <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="10%">
                         Page Size
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPageSize" AutoPostBack="true"
                                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                 </asp:TableRow>
             </asp:Table>
        </PagerTemplate>
```

**Compilation Error** 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Line 113:                     <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="10%">
Line 114:                         Page Size
Line 115:                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPageSize" AutoPostBack="true"
Line 116:                                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged">
Line 117:                                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
```

It makes no sense because I do have the `ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged` method in my code behind file:

```
protected void ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlPageSize = (gvRecordsList.BottomPagerRow).FindControl("ddlPageSize") as DropDownList;
            gvRecordsList.PageSize = int.Parse(ddlPageSize.SelectedValue);
        }
```

anyone know what this could be?

Comment: try to clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: Hi first clean solution and after rebuild your project. Try too create again this event maybe this could help you

Comment: Now getting: Could not load type 'PresentationTier.Global'.
`@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="PresentationTier.Global" Language="C#" %>` after cleaning

Comment: @sd_dracula You can update the original question